# How to display navigation drawer in xamarin forms on button / icon click

Tags: xamarin.forms, navigation-drawer

I am trying to create a navigation drawer for pages in my app. I was able to use MasterDetailPage and get side bar on swipe. How can I display side bar on button click or item click of detail page? Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [IsPresented](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Xamarin.Forms.MasterDetailPage.IsPresented/) property of MasterDetailPage to display the Master page programatically

Comment: One more query, If I want to have navigation drawer in multiple pages, is it required to define each page as MasterDetailPage or can we have a common MasterDetailPage?

Comment: You would typically have one MD and just vary the detail content as the user navigates

Comment: In my app, I have navigation between detail pages also. In that case I would have to create multiple instance of pages. Is there  any way to avoid this?

Comment: Your Detail should be a NavigationPage that then contains your content.  As you navigate between content pages, the Master page should still be accessible

Comment: In my first page, I have options detail1,detail2,detail3. These three are content pages and these three pages should have navigation drawer.  When I navigate from firstpage to detail1 page, Im able to view navigationdrawer without issue. Coming back to first page and moving to detail2 page Im getting exception - "System.InvalidOperationException: Master must not already have a parent."

Comment: You should really ask this as a new question

Answer (score 0):

You can refere Xamarin.Forms example for MasterDetailPage 
https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/Navigation/MasterDetailPage

If you click some item on navigateion drawer, using following command you can display new detail page.

Detail = new NavigationPage ((Page)Activator.CreateInstance (item.TargetType));

```
public MainPage ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();

        masterPage.ListView.ItemSelected += OnItemSelected;

        if (Device.OS == TargetPlatform.Windows) {
            Master.Icon = "swap.png";
        }
    }

    void OnItemSelected (object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var item = e.SelectedItem as MasterPageItem;
        if (item != null) {
            Detail = new NavigationPage ((Page)Activator.CreateInstance (item.TargetType));
            masterPage.ListView.SelectedItem = null;
            IsPresented = false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. But my question was related to displaying master on click, not detail. Anyway Thanks for the info.